# set value of column1 to value of column2 based on value of column1

Tags: python, pandas, replace, comparison

Trying to change values in column 1 to the values found in column 2 if the values in column 1 == 'nan'.

```
for row in df.column_1:
    if row == 'nan':
       df.column_1 == df.column_2
```

But no changes are seen.

Desired Before and After: [sorry, graphic won't upload at the moment]

Comment: df.column_1=df.column_1.fillna(df.column_2)

Comment: I should have mentioned that I tried that too. Does not work.

Comment: Ok then Let me work it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st `'nan'` is not `NaN`, if we want to use `fillna` we need `replace`

```
df.column_1=df.column_1.replace('nan',np.nan).fillna(df.column_2)
```

or we just using `np.where`

```
df.column_1=np.where(df.column_1=='nan',df.column_2,df.column_1)
```

Comment: Thanks Wen, the second solution (np.where) worked. The first one (.replace) did not.

Comment: Taking out the curly brackets allows the first solution to work for my issue. I tried to take out the curlies in an edit, but it said I need to change at least 6 characters to make an edit. Strange.

Comment: @spacedustpi yep , I miss type the dataframe replace to series  sorry about that